# Как добавить библиотеку SDL в CMAKE?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, cmake, sdl

Впервые изучаю CMAKE, учусь подключению библиотек и хейдеров.
Желательно подробное объяснение что к чему.

```
> inc
| > SDL
| |   SDL.h
| |   ...
> lib
| > SDL
| | > x64
| | |   SDL2.dll
| | |   SDL2.lib
| | |   SDL2main.lib
| | |   SDL2test.lib
| | > x86
| | |   SDL2.dll
| | |   SDL2.lib
| | |   SDL2main.lib
| | |   SDL2test.lib
  main.cpp
  CMakeLists.txt
```

## Файл: ./CMakeLists.txt

```html
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)

project(cuongraph)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")

# IMPORT SDL HEADERS
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/inc")

# IMPORT LIBRARIES
if (${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P} MATCHES 8)
    set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/x64/SDL2.lib;${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/x64/SDL2main.lib")
else ()
    set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/x86/SDL2.lib;${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/x86/SDL2main.lib")
endif ()

string(STRIP "${SDL2_LIBRARIES}" SDL2_LIBRARIES)

#ADD EXECUTABLES
add_executable(cuongraph main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(cuongraph inc SDL2)
```

## Сообщение об ошибке

```html
[cmake] Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
[cmake] Configuring done
[cmake] Generating done
[build] Запуск сборки.
[proc] Выполнение команды: "C:\Program Files\cmake-3.13.0-rc1-win64-x64\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/Users/arch/.vscode/repos/cuongraph/build --config Debug --target cuongraph -- /maxcpucount:10
[build] Microsoft (R) Build Engine версии 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 для .NET Framework
[build] (C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.
[build] 
[build] Сборка начата 28.01.2021 14:14:58.
[build]      1>Проект "C:\Users\arch\.vscode\repos\cuongraph\build\cuongraph.vcxproj" в узле 1 (целевые объекты по умолчанию).
[build]      1>Проект "C:\Users\arch\.vscode\repos\cuongraph\build\cuongraph.vcxproj" (1) выполняет сборку "C:\Users\arch\.vscode\repos\cuongraph\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (2) в узле 1 (целевые объекты по умолчанию).
[build]      2>InitializeBuildStatus:
[build]          Создание "win32\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild", так как было задано "AlwaysCreate".
[build]        CustomBuild:
[build]          Для всех выходных данных обновления не требуется.
[build]        FinalizeBuildStatus:
[build]          Файл "win32\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" удаляется.
[build]          Обращение к "win32\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate".
[build]      2>Сборка проекта "C:\Users\arch\.vscode\repos\cuongraph\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" завершена (целевые объекты по умолчанию).
[build]      1>InitializeBuildStatus:
[build]          Обращение к "cuongraph.dir\Debug\cuongraph.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
[build]        CustomBuild:
[build]          Для всех выходных данных обновления не требуется.
[build]        ClCompile:
[build]          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x86\CL.exe /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"cuongraph.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cuongraph.dir\Debug\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue  -std=c++0x C:\Users\arch\.vscode\repos\cuongraph\main.cpp
[build]      1>cl : командная строка warning D9002: пропуск неизвестного параметра "-std=c++0x" [C:\Users\arch\.vscode\repos\cuongraph\build\cuongraph.vcxproj]
[build]          main.cpp
[build]        Link:
[build]          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x86\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\Users\arch\.vscode\repos\cuongraph\build\Debug\cuongraph.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO inc.lib SDL2.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"C:/Users/arch/.vscode/repos/cuongraph/build/Debug/cuongraph.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:/Users/arch/.vscode/repos/cuongraph/build/Debug/cuongraph.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH  /machine:X86 cuongraph.dir\Debug\main.obj
[build]      1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: эх єфрхЄё  юЄъЁ√Є№ Їрщы "inc.lib" [C:\Users\arch\.vscode\repos\cuongraph\build\cuongraph.vcxproj]
[build]      1>Сборка проекта "C:\Users\arch\.vscode\repos\cuongraph\build\cuongraph.vcxproj" завершена (целевые объекты по умолчанию) с ошибкой.
[build] 
[build] Ошибка сборки.
[build] 
[build]        "C:\Users\arch\.vscode\repos\cuongraph\build\cuongraph.vcxproj" (целевой объект по умолчанию) (1) ->
[build]        (ClCompile конечный объект) -> 
[build]          cl : командная строка warning D9002: пропуск неизвестного параметра "-std=c++0x" [C:\Users\arch\.vscode\repos\cuongraph\build\cuongraph.vcxproj]
[build] 
[build] 
[build]        "C:\Users\arch\.vscode\repos\cuongraph\build\cuongraph.vcxproj" (целевой объект по умолчанию) (1) ->
[build]        (Link конечный объект) -> 
[build]          LINK : fatal error LNK1104: эх єфрхЄё  юЄъЁ√Є№ Їрщы "inc.lib" [C:\Users\arch\.vscode\repos\cuongraph\build\cuongraph.vcxproj]
[build] 
[build]     Предупреждений: 1
[build]     Ошибок: 1
[build] 
[build] Прошло времени 00:00:01.21
[build] Сборка выполнена с кодом выхода 1.
```

Comment: `-std=c++0x` - такой флаг понимают только GCC/Clang. У cmake-а должна быть встроенная переменная для выбора версии стандарта.

Comment: sdl прекрасно поддерживает cmake - зачем писать собственный велописед с квадратными колесами? Используйте find_package или add_subdirectory (если используете sdl в качестве sub-project)